# Fetched data is not showing in an IOS app

Tags: json, swift

I'm building an ios app using SwiftUI for frontend and ts for API.

I've tried printing the fetched data out using `List(results) { result in`... and then `Text(result.current_button.title)` instead of showing the data I had a white space there.

Now I'm trying to solve the problem using `ForEach(list.datas){` , but it's also now showing.

> **How do I print the fetched data on the app's screen?**

```swift
import SwiftUI
class MainScreenVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var datas = [MainScreenStruct]()
    init() {
        loadData()
    }
    func loadData() {
        print("Fetching started")
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/getMainScreen")
        else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        let json: [String: Any] = ["grade": "12R",
                                   "group": ["matemaatika": "G1",
                                             "eesti keel": "G2"]]
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode([MainScreenStruct].self, from: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    //DispatchQueue.global().async {
                        self.datas = response
                    }
                    return
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct MainScreen: View{
    @StateObject var list = MainScreenVM()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            LinearGradient(colors: [.pink, .orange], //if all lessons are finished or a weekend than fun color
                           startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    ProgressView(value: 2, total: 5) //value and total depends on the amount of lessons and lessons done
                        .padding()
                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text("Lessons done")
                                .font(.system(size: 20))
                            Label("3", systemImage: "house.fill") //instead of actual amount "300"
                        }
                        .padding()
                        Spacer()
                        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                            Text("Lessons left")
                                .font(.system(size: 20))
                            Label("2", systemImage: "flag.checkered.2.crossed")
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    
                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .center) {
                            Button(action: {
                                print("VENE SUUR SÖÖGISAAL")
                            }) {
                                ForEach(list.datas) { item in
                                    HStack{
                                        Image(systemName: "brain.head.profile")
                                            .font(.largeTitle)
                                        Text(item.current_button.title)
                                    }
                                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .padding()
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .background(LinearGradient(colors: [.indigo, .accentColor],
                                                               startPoint: .bottomTrailing, endPoint: .leading))
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 5.0)
                                    .padding()
                                }
                            }
                            VStack() {
                                Text("Ends in {0} hours {20} minutes {4} seconds")
                                
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .center) {
                            Button(action: {
                                print("VENE SUUR SÖÖGISAAL")
                            }) {
                                HStack{
                                    Image(systemName: "books.vertical.fill")
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                    Text("Next lesson is {English}")
                                        .font(.subheadline  )
                                }
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .padding()
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .background(LinearGradient(colors: [.indigo, .accentColor],
                                                           startPoint: .bottomTrailing, endPoint: .leading))
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 5.0)
                                .padding()
                            }
                            Text("The lesson starts at {14:50}")
                        }
                    }
                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .center) {
                            Button(action: {
                                print("VENE SUUR SÖÖGISAAL")
                            }) {
                                HStack{
                                    Image(systemName: "fork.knife.circle.fill")
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                    Text("Lunch is in 1 hour 15 minutes 30 seconds")
                                        .font(.subheadline  )
                                }
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .padding()
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .background(LinearGradient(colors: [.indigo, .accentColor],
                                                           startPoint: .bottomTrailing, endPoint: .leading))
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 5.0)
                                .padding()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct TimeLeft_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainScreen()
    }
}
```

[image: My screen preview is currently looking like that]

Comment: Don't say `try?`. If there's a decoding error, you are throwing away the valuable info that the decoder is trying to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

```
class VM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts: [Post] = []
    @Published var errorString:Bool = false
    
    init() {
        getDataFromAPI()
    }
    
    func getDataFromAPI() {
        // Make a request to your localhost to retrieve the list of users
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/posts") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching users: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.errorString = true
                }
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                // Parse the JSON data and create an array of User objects
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                let posts = try jsonDecoder.decode([Post].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.posts = posts
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error parsing JSON: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

This is my view model and fetch func. You can change the code as you need.

Comment: Prefer printing `error` over `error.localizedDescription`, especially with `JSONDecoder`, since it will skip all useful information on why it failed when it happens.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).